# How do I get a perfect Regression Line in scikit learn,

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I was trying to visualize the regression line but, this is how I get it

[image]

Comment: the fitted model has the intercept and coefficients, try plotting a line with it

Comment: If you mean linear fit, then there's matplotlib documentation for that

Comment: This is going to be somewhat hard to reproduce without example input data

Comment: Try sorting your inputs.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable response. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without you providing all your code we can't help but guess.  You should try to reproduce the [Scikit-Learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) below.  I made a minor change to have it plot the training data as you are attempting.  Once you get that working swap the diabetes data with your own data.

```
# Code source: Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

# Load the diabetes dataset
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

# Use only one feature
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]

# Split the data into training/testing sets
diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
diabetes_X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)

# Make predictions using the testing set
diabetes_y_pred = regr.predict(diabetes_X_test)

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f"
  % mean_squared_error(diabetes_y_test, diabetes_y_pred))
# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % r2_score(diabetes_y_test, diabetes_y_pred))

# Plot outputs - test data
#plt.scatter(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_test,  color='black')
#plt.plot(diabetes_X_test, diabetes_y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)

# Plot outputs - training data
plt.scatter(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train,  color='black')
plt.plot(diabetes_X_train, regr.predict(diabetes_X_train), color='blue', linewidth=3)

plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  Your post is very helpful.